# Javascript drop down menu for wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm trying to create a javascript menu for my menu I posted a question the other day about a css drop-down but its just to tricky to do that.

Instead I'm thinking script, can someone give me a suitable javascript code that might work in IE? [Here is a link to my test website](http://www.webcarepreview.co.uk/mandalandscaping).

I've tried various other jQuery, but they all rely on the parent ul being a class but as its dynamic content I'm not able to change this / don't want to because I would have to change it for each website and every other website I make. If you have a look at the source code on this website you can see what I mean. The website is quite well comented and you can view the menu online 128 roughly and I can't stress enough how this must be compatible in IE.

Comment: Have you seen superfish? http://kav.in/wordpress-superfish-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins available 
1-
[Dropdown Menu Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dropdown-menu-widget/)
2-[Wordpress CSS Dropdown Menu](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-css-drop-down-menu/) 
3-[Ryans Wordpress Dropdown Menu](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ryans-suckerfish-wordpress-dropdown-menu/) 
 4-[Wordpress Superfish](http://kav.in/wordpress-superfish-dropdown-menu)

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically set the class with jQuery and then initialise the superfish menu. It works in IE6.